# Selenium: can't screenshot element in mouse hover state

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working with Selenium for Python and Chrome webdriver to navigate to a page, scroll to an element, mouse hover over that element, and capture a screenshot of that element in its hover state.  However, when using ActionChains().move_to_element() for hovering, it removes the hover state before/during the screenshot (depends on if there is an animation).

JavaScript's `element.focus()` doesn't always work (i.e. sometimes keyboard focus and mouse focus don't trigger the same hover state).  For those that have animations, the screenshot will sometimes trigger in time to catch a good frame in the animation, but it isn't consistent at all.  I also noticed that taking a normal screenshot with `WIN+PrtSc` has a similar outcome.

Why is this happening, and is there a way that I can prevent it?

Comment: Please always provide a minimum reproducible work/code snippets in order to reproduce the error and thus provide you some way around to solve it. 


https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask